# CSS h1 positioning

Tags: css, position, element

I'm trying to get the text that says "Test" inside of the white DIV, beside the compass logo. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here or how to work around this. Here's an image of what it's looking like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ayZA.jpg

Here's my CSS:

```
#nav{
clear: both;
margin-top: 20px;
background-color: #FFF;
width: 45%;
height: 75px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.46);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.46);
box-shadow:         0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.46);
}
img.logo{
margin-top: -15px;
display: inline;
}
h1.title{
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 2.5em;
color: #FFEA00;
display: inline;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <img class="logo" src="images/compass.png" alt="Compass" />
    <h1 class="title">Test</h1>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not floating anything in that css, clear is not going to help you.

Comment: and you're using negative margin....

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal What would be the proper alternative to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: remove negative margin...

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal Whoops, didn't even notice that I had it on my CSS for h1.title. Thought you were pointing it out for the image. Any solutions for how I can get the text to position properly?

Comment: Very difficult to determine based on what you've provided, but create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) displaying the layout you currently have.

Comment: you have negative margin for image too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the image to appear above the `h1`, you just need to apply `position:absolute;` to the image itself, and you can then remove some unnecessary CSS :)

Here's the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/mk86L1hw/)** of it in action

**CSS**

You just need `position:absolute` to allow the text to move underneath the image, as (loosely speaking) `position:absolute` [removes the target element from it's position in the semantic flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values) by positioning it against it's nearest positioned ancestor

```
img.logo{
    /*margin-top: -15px;*/
    /*display:inline;*/
    position:absolute;
```

}

You can then remove some of your other CSS too:

```
h1.title{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: red;
    /*display: inline;*/ 
    /*margin-top: -500px;*/
}
```